# Crop package axes marks

Tags: printing, crop

I am preparing a document for printing. My bookbinder asked for long (vertical) axes marks on every page, for folding the signatures. The axes marks should start 1cm from the final page and go all the way to the edge of the real paper. I'm using the `crop` package. On the documentation, I found the definition of the axes:

```
\newcommand*\CROP@@upaxis{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\unitlength\p@\thinlines
\put(0,2){\line(0,1){11}}
\end{picture}%
}

\newcommand*\CROP@@loaxis{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\unitlength\p@\thinlines
\put(0,-2){\line(0,-1){11}}
\end{picture}%
}
```

How can I modify these definitions in order to make those axes longer? A rather naïve MNWE would go like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=550mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[cam,axes,center,width=590mm,height=300mm,landscape,noinfo]{crop}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\CROP@@upaxis{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\unitlength\p@\thinlines
\put(0,2){\line(0,1){11}}
\end{picture}%
}

\renewcommand*\CROP@@loaxis{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\unitlength\p@\thinlines
\put(0,-2){\line(0,-1){11}}
\end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,signature=16,noautoscale]{mnwe.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

But I changed the numbers in `\put(){\line(){}}` and nothing happened.

Note: I also checked other packages, like `zwpagelayout` and they don't have axes marks.